# Android Layout Designer can't load platform's drawable resources when a ListFragment added

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I'm using Eclipse on 64 bit Windows 7. When I add a ListFragment to my layout in Android Layout Designer's "Graphical Layout" tab these messages appear:

```
Failed lot load C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable-mdpi\spinner_76_outer_holo.png
Failed to parse file C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable\progress_large_holo.xml
Failed lot load C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable-mdpi\list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png
Failed to parse file C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable\list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml
Failed to parse file C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable\list_selector_holo_dark.xml
Failed lot load C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable-mdpi\list_divider_holo_dark.9.png
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

And that's the content of the Error Log, I'm only pasting the first part of it, since it is very long (although I have cleaned the old ones):

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-01-24 02:58:17.134
!MESSAGE company.xml: Failed lot load C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable-mdpi\spinner_76_outer_holo.png
!STACK 0
javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG metadata
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:695)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1314)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1601)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1286)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:97)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:233)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeResources.getDrawable(BridgeResources.java:167)
    at android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable.inflate(RotateDrawable.java:242)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:832)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:165)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:832)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:769)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:208)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:775)
    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:282)
    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:234)
    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:501)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:84)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:129)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:83)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:86)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
    at android.app.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.java:193)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:708)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:978)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4090)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:659)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:129)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:83)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:367)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1323)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1077)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:903)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(LayoutEditor.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:607)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.selectDefaultPage(AndroidXmlEditor.java:381)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.addPages(AndroidXmlEditor.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2945)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2764)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readFully(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:330)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:565)
    at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readUTF(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:309)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.parse_iTXt_chunk(PNGImageReader.java:443)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:652)
    ... 115 more
```

Comment: Let's the the first one as an example. Can you verify that the file `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable-mdpi\spinner_76_outer_holo.png` exists and that it has the proper permissions?

Comment: @MarvinPinto, the file exists and my user can read and execute.

Comment: Did you come across either [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627770/how-to-repair-an-eclipse-android-installation-png-load-problems-in-the-graphica) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894218/error-reading-png-metadata-android-ui-designer-within-eclipse) question?

Comment: @MarvinPinto The first question's answer is not useful but the second question's answer is what I'm looking for. It worked after installing a new JRE.

Comment: Excellent! As a service to the community, could you write up the details of what you did to make it work (as an **answer**), and then **accept** your answer whenever you're allowed to.

Comment: @MarvinPinto OK, I will add when I'm able to. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple. I installed another JRE (JRE 7) and ran Eclipse with it. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was actually a bit different than this...

My drawable files were taken from the resources of an iPhone project, which had apparently been optimized for android by changing the ARGB data to ABGR data. Unfortunately, whilst Xcode, Preview, and every other program on my Mac dealt with these files wonderfully, eclipse simply could not.

In the end, I opened the images in an image editing program that could handle it (I use Pixelmator), copied the pixel content, made a new image and pasted it in there.

A bit of a hack, but that's what did it for me.